# Color.getColor(String, int) - random color

Tags: java, random, colors, jbutton, setbackground

I'm trying to set the random color of JButton object by:

`button.setBackground(Color.getColor(null,(int) (Math.random() * 255 + 1)));`

but it only produces different shades of blue. Thanks.

Comment: @AmitBera That is incorrect.  `Math.random()` returns a `double`, promoting to `double` before multiplying by `255`.  The `int` cast happens last due to the parentheses.  But it won't result in `0`; this expression's range is `1` through `255`.  To get a range of `0` through `255`, `(int) (Math.random() * 256)` will do.

Comment: @rgettman Sorry I was wrong. I have just misplaced the braces during testing. I will delete my comment. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following:-

```
int red = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
int green = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
button.setBackground(new Color(red, green, blue));
```

Comment: You shouldn't add 1, it's expecting 0-255 for the RGB values. Just multiply the random output by 256.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want an opaque color, the color value needs to be 24 bits wide, with 8 bits for each of the these colors: red, green, blue.

Try this:

```
button.setBackground(new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting shades of blue because you can only fill the 8 least significant bits with `(int) (Math.random() * 255 + 1)`, which control the blue intensity.  You need the ability to control all 24 bits (or 32 if you include transparency).

With a `java.util.Random` object `rnd`:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

- Express the [color as 3 `float` values from 0.0 - 1.0](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-float-float-float-):

  ```
  new Color(rnd.nextFloat(), rnd.nextFloat(), rnd.nextFloat())
  ```
- Express the [color as an `int`, with 24 bits affected](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-int-):

  ```
  new Color(rnd.nextInt(1<<24));
  ```
- Express the [color as 3 `int`s 0-255 each, red/green/blue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-int-int-int-):

  ```
  new Color(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, when you get a Color object with an integer, it stores blue in bits 0-7, green in bits 8-15, and red in bits 16-23 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int)

To compensate, add each component together for something like this

```
public int GetRandomColorInt()
{
    return (Math.random() * Math.pow(2,8)) //blue
        + (Math.random() * Math.pow(2,16)) //green
        + (Math.random() * Math.pow(2,24) ) //red

}
```

And in your set background call,

```
button.setBackground(Color.getColor(null,(int) GetRandomColorInt()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Color constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int)).
By only using numbers between 0 and 255, you are using a variety of blues.
If you want to properly use this according to your code and your Color contructor, you can use this:

```
int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255 + 1);
int blue= (int) (Math.random() * 255 + 1);
int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255 + 1);
button.setBackground(Color.getColor(null, red * blue * green));
```

By the way, you can use other Color constructor such as:

```
Color color = new Color(red, green, blue));
button.setBackground(color);
```